# How can I print the binary representation of a 8 bit int without using any conditional or while loops?

Tags: c

I have a problem that I am working on it for one week and can't get a good solving method. I have to get the binary representation of an 8 bit integer in C, without using any if or while loops. I find it impossible because I have to use only bitwise operators (tips given: bit shifting and masking). Any help will be much apreciated!

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 00000111 |
| 127 | 01111111 |

Since I don't have a solving method I don't have any versions. I need the logic behind it!

Comment: You can just expand the loop, that technically meets the criteria.

Comment: Unroll the loop. Output the value of each bit, using a mask and a shift. Leftmost bit: `printf("%d", (num >> 7) & 1);`

Comment: Have you *tried* bit-shifting and masking? How far did you get? What code do you have to review?

Comment: If you don't want to unroll the loop there's always recursion.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for explaining! I did it by unrolling the loop.

Comment: If you only have to worry about singular bytes, then a 256-element lookup table is your easiest bet :D

Comment: @Barmar It's not a homework question. I just wanted to know how I can deal with bitwise operators on my class by giving myself some exercises. But thanks for the advice on homework's.

Comment: Sorry, arbitrary restrictions like "you can't use loops" almost always come from homework assignments or puzzle sites, so it was a natural assumption.

Comment: And if it didn't come from an assignment, where did the "tips given" come from? I just don't see how this is just personal curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Computing such a representation is as simple as figuring out whether bits at position 0 to 7 are on or off. A way of doing this is performing a binary AND and checking if the result is zero or not.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BIT0 1 << 0
#define BIT1 1 << 1
#define BIT2 1 << 2
#define BIT3 1 << 3
#define BIT4 1 << 4
#define BIT5 1 << 5
#define BIT6 1 << 6
#define BIT7 1 << 7

int main()
{
    unsigned num = 7;
    unsigned representation[8] = {
        !!(BIT0 & num),
        !!(BIT1 & num),
        !!(BIT2 & num),
        !!(BIT3 & num),
        !!(BIT4 & num),
        !!(BIT5 & num),
        !!(BIT6 & num),
        !!(BIT7 & num),
    };

    // This loop is not part of the solution. 
    // It just prints the computed representation.
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%d", representation[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
00000111
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8WqTvhPTd)

A useful tool in this case is to define a macro to compute the value of a specific bit, e.g.:

```
define BIT(pos, num) !!(1 << (pos) & (num))
```

which could be used to compute on the fly the value of a bit at a position e.g. bit 2 would be `BIT(2, number)` and this means you can easily compute representations as the one by @user3386109 in the comments:

```
char representation[] = {
  BIT(7, number) + '0',
  BIT(6, number) + '0',
  BIT(5, number) + '0',
  BIT(4, number) + '0',
  BIT(3, number) + '0',
  BIT(2, number) + '0',
  BIT(1, number) + '0',
  BIT(0, number) + '0',
};
```

Comment: The question is tagged C.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops my bad. I rephrased.

Comment: You can get rid of the loop by changing `unsigned representation[8]` to `char representation[9]`, and then creating the output string directly. E.g. `{ !!(BIT7 & num) + '0', ... }`

Comment: @user3386109 what loop ?

Comment: The loop at the end that you claim doesn't count.

Comment: @user3386109 That's there just to print the array. I'm assuming the array is the representation. OP doesn't mention they want a string output

Comment: I guess it's up to OP to clarify what "output" actually means.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeap it is a bit loosely specified. Good thing about `char[8]` over `unsigned[8]` is it's more compact I give you that. Using it as a string would require reversing the order (`BIT7` goes first in the array initialization) though.